# Filepath on different pages on website

Tags: html, file, path, directory, exists

If I set a filepath for an image like src="images/anotherFolder/picture.jpg" on the start page of my website it works great. But if I then visit www.mywebsite.com/albums and use the same src, it doesn't work at all. And if check the image path given in Chrome I see that it's looking for an image with an URL which looks like this:
www.mywebsite.com/albums/images/anotherFolder/picture.jpg

instead of this:

www.mywebsite.com/images/anotherFolder/picture.jpg

So I thought that I would use a source that looked like this instead:
src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/anotherFolder/edit.jpg" which works on both pages BUT then PHP functions such as is_file, is_readable, file_exists wont work properly.

So, what to do?

**ADDED**

I use a .htaccess file to rewrite the URL from http://www.mywebsite.com/albums?id=123 to http://www.mywebsite.com/albums/123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called relative paths.
If you want a relative path to the root of your site, you should start with a slash: `/`

```
src="/images/anotherFolder/picture.jpg"
```

And if you want relative path to the parent folder, you should start with two dots and a slash: `../`

So if you are in www.mywebsite.com/albums,

```
src="../images/anotherFolder/picture.jpg"
```

and if you are in www.mywebsite.com/albums/aaa,

```
src="../../images/anotherFolder/picture.jpg"
```

**Edit:**

It seems that `is_file` doesn't work with relative paths from root, but it works with `../`.
If you prefer relative paths from root, you can use

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/anotherFolder/picture.jpg"
```

Comment: Are there any alternatives to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] that works with XAMPP?

Comment: @Oskwish I don't have XAMPP so I don't know, but I think it should work. If I'm right, in XAMPP, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is "c:\xampp\xampp\htdocs", which is the root of your site, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use src="./images/anotherFolder/edit.jpg"

Comment: Doesn't work :/ Should maybe add that I use a .htaccess file to rewrite the URL from http://www.mywebsite.com/albums?id=123 to http://www.mywebsite.com/albums/123